# HTML5 Js increment

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a series of circles using the HTML5 canvas element. I am using a while loop to increment the size of the circles. I am attempting to increment them by three but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

```
    var cirSize = 2;

    while (cirSize < 400)
      {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle="#000000"; 
        ctx.arc(480,480,cirSize++,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.stroke();
        alert(cirSize)
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Minor note:'Increment' means 'increase by one'. 'Increment by three' is nonsensical.

Comment: @KendallFrey Thanks for your input but broadly speaking anytime you increase an amount it's an increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cirSize++` will increment by one, so will `++cirSize`. But there's a difference. The former will *return* the value of `cirSize` first and *then* increment. While the latter will *increment first* and *then* return the value of `cirSize`

```
var cirSize = 2;

while (cirSize < 400)
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000000"; 
    ctx.arc(480,480,cirSize,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.stroke();
    cirSize += 3; // here's the change.
    alert(cirSize)
  }
```